# animate span with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some issue with js or css.
Imagine **we have 2** `<span>`s:

first - display:block, 2d - display none.

Onclick *I need to show second one with animation slide-up*.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById('second').style.display = "-webkit-flex";
```

```html
<span id="first" style="display:block">Auto</span>
<span id="second" style="animation: slide-up 1s ease;display:none">Airlines</span>
```

But animation is not appearing.

Comment: where are you defining the `slide-up` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to add the animation _after_ the span is display flex. Also stop using the prefixed flex properties.

Comment: Have you tried creating a CSS class and assigning it to your span dynamically in JS?

Comment: can you don't just change the opacity? and change some margin during the transition to do a slide up annimation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only [some CSS properties can be animated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties). `display` is not one of them.

Typically a "slide-up" animation (and you failed to include the definition of yours in your [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) would animate the `top` property to move it into position.